# I am getting indentation error in python. could someone please help me get through this

Tags: python-2.7

def outlierCleaner(predictions, ages, net_worths):

```
error=abs(predictions-net_worths)
print type(error)
cleaned_data = []


### your code goes here


return cleaned_data
```

Error:
File "outlier_cleaner.py", line 14
print type(error)
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete code could have helped more but your indentation in the function is wrong.

```
#declare you function
def outlierCleaner(predictions, ages, net_worths):
    # the code below should have a standard ident
    error=abs(predictions-net_worths)
    print(error)
    cleaned_data = []
    ### your code goes here
    return cleaned_data
```